# Feature map of Polynomial Kernel

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

The polynomial kernel is defined as

$k(x,x') = (\langle x,x' \rangle +c)^m $

The feature map for polynomial kernel as introduced by my lecturer is given as

$\phi:x \mapsto c_i(x_1^{i_1}+x_2^{i_2}+x_3^{i_3},....x_n^{i_n})_{i=(i_1,i_2,....i_d) \in \mathbb{N}_0^d : \sum_{j=1}^n i_j \leq m}$ $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$

I want to prove that polynomial kernel is a kernel using the above-mentioned feature map. The problem which I am facing is how to interpret this feature map to formally start the proof.

Comment: what is exactly $c_i$ where $i=(i_1,...,i_d)$?

Comment: i am not sure but i guess its the constant term for each input feature!

Comment: so, it’s rather $c$?

Comment: I think so! that makes much more sense!